# Get the key of an object via Firebase v9 queries

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

[image: Each Alphabet("A", "B", "C", "D") is an array of objects and each object having and id and name.]

I want to write a function so that it returns me the key i.e ("A" || "B" || "C" || "D" || null) if an id already exists in any of the option. So my idea is that a user can only choose one option among(A,B,C,D). Can you suggest me any firebase query(JavaScript) for doing so.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to perform an OR type query like that across multiple fields in Firestore, not is there a way to have a condition on just part of an array element.

You will either have to perform a separate query for each field and merge the results in your code, or (and more likely) add an **additional** field to the documents with all the IDs from the all the other fields and then perform the query on that (merged) field.